# dangers are in giving public execute permissions to the httpdocs

Tags: httpd, linux, file-permissions

I am new to linux webhosting services and I have question in my mind which is there any danger are in giving public execute permissions to the httpdocs

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is any security issue with the usual default web servers configuration. Though, some servers may be configured to treat executable files as CGI scripts which can give other results then expected when such file is referenced.

Usually write permissions are those you should worry about most.